# How can I use custom hooks in react redux actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

What I'm trying to do here is to simplify the code using hooks

Here is the action file

```
export const getThings = (num) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: constants.GET_HOME_PAGE_REQ });
    const [res, error] = useFetch('get', api + "/latest/" + num, {});
    useEffect(() => {
        res && dispatch({
            type: constants.GET_HOME_PAGE_RES,
            status: res.status,
            payload: res.data.message,
        });
    }, [res, dispatch]);
    useEffect(() => {
        error && dispatch({
            type: constants.GET_HOME_PAGE_ERROR,
            message: error.message,
            status: error.status,
        });
    } , [error, dispatch]);
};
```

and the error I'm getting

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: `const [res, error] = useFetch('get', api + "/latest/" + num, {});` this is an invalid call. Hook can be called inside of the body of a function component. So don't call in your async function `getThings`.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of React hooks (and custom hooks) is to manage the state and the lifecycle of React functional components. So it doesn't make sense to use it outside a react component and you are not allowed to do so, therefore the console error. If you just want to fetch some data from an API, create a variable like this:

```
const result = await fetch(...)
```

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the react hooks like useEffect, useFetch inside a body of a function based component.it cannot be used inside normal javascript functions, u have used it in the return portion of that function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).